# I go to (and I am in) many places

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

I go to (and I am in) many places

I know (and have) different faces

You may think about me every day

You may even need me to keep sane

I live around rockets in outer space

I am often talked about during a race

What am I?

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Man

I go to (and I am in) many places

> Man goes to many places and the text is literally in 'man'y.

I know (and have) different faces

> Man has different faces, which can mean we are different people.

You may think about me every day

> We think about people (or man) everyday.

You may even need me to keep sane

> People (man) are a social creatures and need other man to stay sane.

I live around rockets in outer space

> Man existence in space is dependant on rockets, so they live around rockets.

I am often talked about during a race

> The people (man) racing are the contestants, so they are the ones talked about

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Time

I go to (and I am in) many places

> Time to go.  Made it in time.

I know (and have) different faces

> Clocks and watches have many different faces

You may think about me every day

> What time is it?  When do we have to be there?

You may even need me to keep sane

> I need some time to myself or I'll go crazy.

I live around rockets in outer space

> Rockets approaching the speed of light have relativistic time distortions (at least in theory and sci-fi).

I am often talked about during a race

> How fast they finished (i.e. in what time) is often talked about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are

**Dream.**

Dream goes everywhere and is in everywhere.

Dream knows and has different faces.

People think their dream everyday.

People may even need dream to keep sane.

Dream is often talked about during a race.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are a...

> Dog

I go to (and I am in) many places.

> Dogs are common around the world.

I know (and have) different faces.

> There are many breeds and dogs know many owners' faces

You may think about me every day.

> You sure do if you own one.

You may even need me to keep sane.

> E.g. a companion dog.

I live around rockets in outer space.

> Many dogs have gone to space.

I am often talked about during a race.

> From the wordplay tag..  dog, to follow or tail, a term often used when racing.